# I am trying to use Swiper, but it shows problem. I have done all steps as shown in Swiper Vue js. Hope you answer

Tags: javascript, html, vue-cli

These dependencies were not found:

- swiper/css in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1-0!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--1-1!./src/components/Clients.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js
- swiper/vue in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1-0!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--1-1!./src/components/Clients.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js

To install them, you can run: npm install --save swiper/css swiper/vue

**But it shows like this**

Answer (score 0):

Use `import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.css'`

[image]